# Can I get config fro database in appModule with @nestjs/cofnig?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I want to use @nestjs to manage configuration files.

Now I have used the following ways to connect mysql and redis.

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize'
import { RedisModule } from 'nestjs-redis'
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { ExampleModule } from './example/example.module'
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module'
import config from './config' // I want to use @nestjs/config instead it

@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot(config.DATABASE),
    RedisModule.register(config.REDIS),
    UserModule,
    ExampleModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot()
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can I get their configuration information in appmodule via @ nestjs / config

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the asynchronous registration methods `forRootAsync` and `registerAsync`. The easiest way to do this is to have a setup like so:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        url: config.get('DATABASE'),
      }),
    }),
    RedisModule.registerAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFacotry: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        url: config.get('REDIS')
      })
    }),
    UserModule,
    ExampleModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    })
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Some of the options and typings may be off, but this should head you in the right direction.